# VM persistent outbound endpoint inside JMS transaction

Tags: transactions, jms, mule

I'm trying to implement a realibility pattern by getting a message from JMS queue and putting it into VM persistent queue transactionally. The point is to ensure a message is either stored in the VM queue (to be asynchronously processed later) or not consumed from JMS queue at all.

This is the relevant config portion I have.

```
<vm:connector name="asyncDbConnector">
    <default-persistent-queue-store/>
</vm:connector>

<endpoint name="asyncDbEndpoint" address="vm://asyncDb" connector-ref="asyncDbConnector" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>

<flow name="jsmInFlow">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint ref="jmsInEndpoint">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>

    <logger message="In jsmInFlow: #[message.payload]"/>

    <outbound-endpoint ref="asyncDbEndpoint" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
</flow>

<flow name="asyncDbFlow">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint ref="asyncDbEndpoint">
        <vm:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </vm:inbound-endpoint>

    <logger message="In asyncDbFlow: #[message.payload]"/>

    ...
</flow>
```

With such config I get "Endpoint is transactional but transaction does not support it". As far as I understood it attempts to execute `asyncDbFlow` synchronously and join the existing transaction but JMS transaction doesn't support VM transactions. Instead I need it to just reliably queue the message and rollback the JMS transaction if the queuing fails. Is it possible with Mule?

Comment: when do that error happen? When executing the first flow or the second one?

Comment: @AleSequeira actually after some digging I realized that this scenario requires usage of multi-resource transactions (Mule EE only) or XA transactions.